# How can I make a custom layout / change header background color … with Tex, Latex, ConTeXt?

Tags: layout, background, latex

currently I produce dynamically [this document](http://download.stephane-klein.info/exemple_document.png) with Python Report Labs… to produce pdf documents.

Now, I would like try to produce this document with Tex / Latex / ConTeXt…

I've some questions :

- how can I make the layout ?
- how can I make header background color ?
- how can I define my custom title (with blue box) ?
- what is the better choice for my project : Latex or ConTeXt ?

What package I need to use ?

- geometry ?
- fancyhdr ?

Have you some example ? some resource ?

Yesterday, I've read many many documentation… and I don't found a solution / example for my questions.

Comment: I need also to use XeTeX for unicode, I have some Russian version of document.

Comment: This question belongs on TeX.stackexchange...

Answer (score 2):

Some useful packages apart from the `fancyhdr` you already mentioned are:

1. [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/) for more control over your section titles
2. [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) for more control over table layout
3. [`PGF/TikZ`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/) for the graphics in your document, i.e., the page turn effect in the corner and maybe the blue boxes (although that might be considered a bit overkill :))
4. [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) for more control over your document layout, but the package is more book-oriented than you need probably
5. [`koma-script`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) might be a good alternative for `memoir` but I'm not familiar with it so I don't know about its weaknesses

This is list is not exhaustive and I am not experienced enough in this kind of typesetting meets lay-out stuff to be of much help, but these are packages that come to my mind given your problem :).

Using [`inputenc`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/inputenc.html) there shouldn't be a problem typesetting Russian text.

Maybe the actual process will be easier in ConTeXt, it is more oriented towards control over your typesetting but I'm not familiar with it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'd certainly do this kind of think in Context rather than Latex: Context permits grid layout, and allows you to define layers for putting text and other graphics on top of background graphics.  But as Pieter says, you could try using TikZ to do this with Latex.

Unicode is no barrier to regular Latex or Context: with either, just specify that you want to use utf-8 as input encoding.

If you do use Latex, don't have headers or footers, and allocate no vertical space for them either.

With Context:

1. *how can I make the layout?* — Use grid layout.
2. *how can I make header background color?* — Use \setupbackground
3. *how can I define my custom title (with blue box) ?*  — I don't understand what you want to do here.

Everything you need to do this, except grid mode and how to put graphics in the background, is documented in [Context an excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mp-cb-en.pdf).  Grid mode is explained in [the Context manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/cont-eni.pdf).  Layers are a bit tricky to get to grips with, but [Layers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers) in the Context wiki is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

With `titlesec` and `color` packages use this in LaTeX head (before `\begin{document}`)

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{color}

% Colors
\definecolor{textcolor}{rgb}{.90,.95,1}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{rgb}{.94,.97,1}

% Header style
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{textcolor}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{}{1em}{{\color{boxcolor}\rule{0.35cm}{0.35cm}}\quad}
```

to make the blue box and change header color, font and remove numbering.